# C++ Stringstream int to string but returns null

Tags: c++, string, int, stringstream

Hi below is my function:

```
string Employee::get_print(void) {

   string out_string;
   stringstream ss;

   ss << e_id << " " << type << endl;
   out_string = ss.str();

   return out_string;
}
```

`e_id` and `type` are `int` and they contain values from the class Employee. But when I pass them into the stringstream they just clear the string when I try to out put it. But if I don't have a `int` in the `ss << "Some text" << endl;` this output fine. What am I doing wrong =S

//Edit

Ok; 
This is the calling code:

```
tmp = cur->get_print();
```

Where tmp is a string and cur is an Employee Object.

This code...

```
stringstream out; 
out << "Test " << e_id << " " << e_type; 
return out.str();
```

Retruns "Test " and nothing else. If I take out `"Test " <<` my returned string is ""

I'm using GCC 4.2 on Mac OS/X 10.6.2 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Works fine for me; can you show the calling code, perhaps?

Comment: You can shorten that code by at least two lines (i.e. 40%, not counting blank lines) without making it any less readable.

Comment: Also what does "they just clear the string" mean?

Comment: I can't see any issue with the code. I need to see more context code. Also, say `get_print()`. And you don't need to create the temporary `string`, just return `ss.str()`.

Comment: Updated the code and tried to explain it more.

Answer (score 1):

I too am unable to reproduce this error. As has been mentioned, don't include the `endl`, as this actually appends a `\n` and is supposed to flush the write buffer. For this use, it is completely unnecessary and may actually lead to undesirable results...However, the code in your edit/update works just fine for me.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int e_id = 5;
   int e_type = 123456;
   stringstream out; 
   out << "Test " << e_id << " " << e_type;
   cout << out.str();
   return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
Test 5 123456
```

My suggestions would be to double check that `e_id` and `e_type` are really just native `int`.

For further testing, you may want to force a cast on the values to see if it helps as such:

`out << "Test " << (int)e_id << " " << (int)e_type;`

Since I'm unable to reproduce this error, I'm afraid I'm unable to help any further. But best of luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have no idea what is going on with `stringstream` I've tried using it in other parts of my code and it doesn't work with integers. Therefore, I have reverted to using the `sprintf` C function:

```
string Employee::get_print(void) {

   char out[50];

   sprintf(out, "%d %d", e_id, e_type);

   string output = out;

   return output;
}
```

This returns the string which is needed.

Comment: Once again, the variable `output` is redundant. Also, I don’t think it’s a good idea that you mask a bug somewhere in your application by avoiding the symptoms. Your initial code was fine. If it produced wrong results this means that there’s a bug *somewhere else*. Your change didn’t fix that bug.

Comment: It was a bug with Xcode, it works fine with NetBeans. (using stringstream)

Answer (score 1):

I have moved into Netbeans and I don't have this problem. So it is an issue with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I think the endl is not needed.  You only need to write endl if you want to write a newline on a file on on std::cout.

Since you write endl, your stringstream will contain a string with 2 lines of which the second is empty.  This probably confuses you.  Remove the endl to get only one line.

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem - GCC and stringstream returning nothing.

As I found out, the trick is that you have to put some *text data* before anything else into the stringstream.

This code...

```
stringstream ss(stringstream::out);
ss << 3.14159;
cout << "'" << ss.str() << "'" << endl;
```

gets you this result:

```
''
```

But if we put a single `""` inside the stringstream first...

```
stringstream ss(stringstream::out);
ss << "" << 3.14159;
cout << "'" << ss.str() << "'" << endl;
```

the result is as expected:

```
'3.14159'
```